# GKE авторизация github actions, добавить разрешение на деплой контейнера container.deployments.create

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud, github-actions

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как добавить разрешение на деплой Docker-контейнера в GKE пользователю, авторизовавшемуся через github actions?

Использую статью: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/deployment/deploying-to-your-cloud-provider/deploying-to-google-kubernetes-engine

Политика доступа:

```
gcloud projects add-iam-policy-binding $GKE_PROJECT \
  --member=serviceAccount:$SA_EMAIL \
  --role=roles/container.admin \
  --role=roles/storage.admin \
  --role=roles/container.clusterAdmin
```

В github actions авторизация по GKE_SA_KEY:

```
- name: Access to cluster
  uses: google-github-actions/get-gke-credentials@fb08709ba27618c31c09e014e1d8364b02e5042e
  with:
    cluster_name: ${{ env.GKE_CLUSTER }}
    location: ${{ env.GKE_ZONE }}
    credentials: ${{ secrets.GKE_SA_KEY }}
```

При запуске `kubectl create deployment gateway --image=$IMAGE_ID:$VERSION` требует разрешения:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Та же команда в Cloud Shell проходит успешно.

В дашборд политики вручную не добавить, Role cant be edited as it inherited from another resource:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/granting-changing-revoking-access

Enable resource manager API, тогда service account появится в списке и можно будет добавить нужную роль.
В моем случае - owner.